# send mail from erlang

Tags: email, ubuntu, erlang

I work in ubuntu 10.10 and I use Erlang.
My goal is to write a code in order to send mail from Erlang.

This is my code:

```
-module(mailer).

-compile(export_all).


send(Destination, Subject, Body) ->
    D = string:join(lists:map( fun(Addr) -> binary_to_list(Addr) end, Destination ), " " ),
    S = io_lib:format("~p",[binary_to_list(Subject)]),
    B = io_lib:format("~p",[binary_to_list(Body)]),
    os:cmd("echo "" ++ B ++ "" | mail -s "" ++ S ++ "" " ++ D).
```

and to execute the send function I try with :

```
Erlang R13B03 (erts-5.7.4) [source] [rq:1] [async-threads:0] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V5.7.4  (abort with ^G)
1> mailer:send([<<"testFrom@mail.com">>, <<"testto@yahoo.fr">>], <<"hello">>, <<"Hello guys">>..                        
"/bin/sh: mail: not found\n"
```

as you see I have this error:

```
/bin/sh: mail: not found
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install -y mail`  :)

Answer (score 8):

I will recommend using an existing smtp library in erlang. [gen_smtp](https://github.com/Vagabond/gen_smtp) is one that I have used in the past. Sending email is as simple as:

`gen_smtp_client:send({"whatever@test.com", ["andrew@hijacked.us"],
 "Subject: testing\r\nFrom: Andrew Thompson \r\nTo: Some Dude \r\n\r\nThis is the email body"},
  [{relay, "smtp.gmail.com"}, {username, "me@gmail.com"}, {password, "mypassword"}]).`

Answer (score 4):

1 You can try use **Sendmail** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sendmail by Erlang, like here - https://github.com/richcarl/sendmail/blob/master/sendmail.erl

2 You can use https://github.com/Vagabond/gen_smtp

3 You can try implemented simple SMTP client use "smtp.gmail" by RFC https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321 and try create something like:

```
connect() ->
  {ok, Socket} = ssl:connect("smtp.gmail.com", 465, [{active, false}], 1000),
  recv(Socket),
  send(Socket, "HELO localhost"),
  send(Socket, "AUTH LOGIN"),
  send(Socket, binary_to_list(base64:encode("me@gmail.com"))),
  send(Socket, binary_to_list(base64:encode("letmein"))),
  send(Socket, "MAIL FROM: <me@gmail.com>"),
  send(Socket, "RCPT TO: <you@mail.com>"),
  send(Socket, "DATA"),
  send_no_receive(Socket, "From: <me@gmail.com>"),
  send_no_receive(Socket, "To: <you@mail.com>"),
  send_no_receive(Socket, "Date: Tue, 20 Jun 2012 20:34:43 +0000"),
  send_no_receive(Socket, "Subject: Hi!"),
  send_no_receive(Socket, ""),
  send_no_receive(Socket, "This was sent from Erlang. So simple!"),
  send_no_receive(Socket, ""),
  send(Socket, "."),
  send(Socket, "QUIT"),
  ssl:close(Socket).
```

More details - http://www.gar1t.com/presentations/2012-07-16-oscon/index.html#slide44

Answer (score 2):

It appears the "mail" command is not available in your system. See e.g. [this tutorial](http://www.quietearth.us/articles/2006/09/25/Ubuntu-Sending-command-line-mail) on how to install it (or google one on your own).